# Netbeans: Designing Graphic User Interface

Tags: java, netbeans

i'm just going to ask why is that every time I run my GUI, it seems like the Frame is not exactly the same on the designer I have been designed?

for example, the textboxes are not align when I run the **UI** but if Im gonna review it in designer, it seems like everything is okay at all? i'm confused.. >.<

Comment: Runnable example would help a lot. I'd also highly recommend that you don't use the form designer until you have a better understanding of the API, including how to use layout managers

Comment: maybe thats my problem right now... ugh*